# Does Openni 2.2 support Kinect v2?

Tags: kinect, openni, nite

I'm using the new kinect on win8.1 and installed the Openni2 and NITE2, but they can't find my kinect.

So what should I do to make it run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenNI doesn't support Kinect (v1 or v2) directly. But you may install a driver for that. I have used successfully the Kinect v1 with OpenNI in windows and Linux... In windows it is easier, you only need to install the Kinect SDK 1.8 for v1... I haven't test it for v2 though, but I am almost sure it doesn't work... most probably you will need to wait for an open driver...

In summary:

> Does Openni 2.2 support Kinect v2?

No

> So what should I do to make it run?

Wait for an open driver of kinect that works with openni

Comment: Yeah I've run it successfully using v1, but seems it can't recognize V2, maybe there haven't been a driver yet.Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the [kinect2 branch in the occipital OpenNI2 repository](https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2/tree/kinect2/Source/Drivers/Kinect2) they seem to be working on a Kinect v2 driver for OpenNI2 based on the official Microsoft SDK. I haven't tested it myself though.

Answer (score 2):

I was also trying to do this for my project and I found that Occipitals' github OpenNI2 source has a functional kinect2 driver in their "Kinect 2" branch. I could build this source and run the NiViewer,exe with Kinect 2.

It's simple:

1.Fork this:[OpenNI2 Kinect2 source](https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2/tree/kinect2/Source/Drivers/Kinect2) and clone a copy on to your computer at desired location, ensure Kinect 2.0 SDK is installed.

2.Build the solution: OpenNI.sln (unload the "Kinect" project if you have no Kinect 1.x SDK installed).

3.After building the OpenNI.sln, you will find Kinect2.dll and Kinect2.lib under directory you forked to>Bin>X64(/32)Debug>OpenNI2>Drivers

4. Copy these to the default directory of the installed OpenNI2 on your system C:\Program Files\OpenNI2\Tools\OpenNI2\Drivers (or the corresponding location in the build is Bin\x64 debug\NiViewer.exe)
5. Run the NiViewer.exe

Comment: Why are you telling people to fork a repo? They can just clone it.

Comment: The question is about NiTE but the answer are for OpenNi, my understanding is that is that they are different stuff, i manage to get the OpenNi on my kinect to with this help but i still miss NiTE.