# Dose NiTE work with Kinect v2

Tags: kinect, nite

I try to make openni2(32bit) and NiTE2(32bit) work with kinectv2 on win10(64bit),and NiViewer did work after I use kinect2.dll from github,but any sample in NiTE2 does not work,so is there any way to get NiTE2 work with Kinectv2?

Comment: If you use Win10, why do you want to use NiTE instead of the Microsoft SDK? The Microsoft SDK provides skeleton tracking, which will most likely work better than NiTE with Kinect v2.

Comment: Ah，I think I foget this

Comment: i need it for linux, This is the 1st steps which isntall OpenNi for Kinect v2: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465516/does-openni-2-2-support-kinect-v2/35087029#35087029

but i still miss NiTE any help is welcome